# Why is this question not being reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question on differences between two types of German doctoral programs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34431/stuctured-vs-individual-german-doctoral-program) was originally rightfully put on hold as being unclear.  The original poster then added information, and the question edited such that it appears to me to now by a  quite clear and useful question. Its reopen vote, however, doesn't seem to be going anywhere.  Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why people where not voting to reopen it. Sometimes the process is slow and you just need to alert people, on either meta or chat, to issues. The question had two reopen votes, and I added mine to reopen it. I think your edit made the question much clearer.

Comment: Note that five users voted on this post in the review queue, so the review was marked "complete" and the post was removed from the queue. [Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/17539) is the review history.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's go back to the Revision history of the question linked to this meta. See https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/34431/revisions

I was the one who cast the first Reopen vote after the OP edited the question. Then jakebeal edited it again to make it better and voted to Reopen. Then the question just sat there until StrongBad, one of our mods (I was going to say our excellent mod, but all of our mods are excellent), reopened it.

The reason I casted the Reopen vote was because I am a regular **Review** queue user. I saw it in the Review because the OP edited it. I examined it and decided to vote to reopen. I believe jake is also a regular Review user. He probably saw it in the Review and then did the Edit and Reopen.

Now, here is the problem I have observed. Not too many of our users use the Review queue. As far as I know, only a handful are regular non-mod Review users. You can check the stats for each Review category. For example, only Peter Jansson and I have three digits number of Reopen reviews. I believe this is one of the reasons the subjct question stayed on limbo stage for so long. Had many users seen it in Review, it would be reopened (or left closed) without mods' intervention.

My answer here naturally raises a question, how do we encourage our users to use Review which is a very good moderating tool? I don't have a good answer for this question. I just keep doing Review myself.

Comment: That's not really accurate. Actually, another three users saw that question in the review queue and voted to leave closed. At that point, the question had been reviewed by five users, the review was considered "complete," and it was no longer in the review queue. [Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/17539) is the review history.

Comment: @ff524 My rep is not enough to see that review history. So, I didn't know that part. That's why I said in the answer: _Had many users seen it in Review, it would be reopened (**or left closed**)_.

Comment: Also of interest: the review by five users was completed in 3.5 hours (not long)

Comment: @ff524 Yea, I now know. However, I rather leave my answer here for the discussion purpose. This meta question turned out to be more complex than I thought. Now I question that should we reopen this question after Review "complete"?

Comment: Also, I just successfully opened that link in another window where I was not signed in. I don't think you need any rep to see it. You can see the outcome of any review you voted on in [your profile](http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/546/scaaahu?tab=activity&sort=reviews); click on your decision (e.g. "leave closed") for any post and it'll show you all of the votes by all reviewers of that post.

Comment: @ff524 Thanks. I learned something very useful today.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason is that the whole `close -> improve -> reopen` strategy is not exactly working well all the time. In my opinion, the strategy `comment -> edit -> problem solved` works better. It is just necessary to decide whether you prefer some good questions staying closed or some bad questions staying open. I prefer the latter.